# Can I perform a left join/merge between two dataframes using regular expressions with pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to perform a left merge using regular expressions in Python that can handle many-to-many relationships.
Example:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d'], columns = ['col1'])
    df1['regex'] = '.*' + df1['col1'] + '.*'

    col1    regex
  0 a   .*a.*
  1 b   .*b.*
  2 c   .*c.*
  3 d   .*d.*

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(['ab','a','cd'], columns = ['col2'])

    col2
  0 ab
  1 a
  2 cd

    # Merge on regex column to col2

    out = pd.DataFrame([['a','ab'],['a','a'],['b','ab'],['c','cd'], 
    ['d','cd']],columns = ['col1','col2'])


    col1    col2
  0 a   ab
  1 a   a
  2 b   ab
  3 c   cd
  4 d   cd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use create a custom function to find all the matching indexes of both the data frames then extract those indexes and use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```
import re
def merge_regex(df1, df2):
    idx = [(i,j) for i,r in enumerate(df1.regex) for j,v in enumerate(df2.col2) if re.match(r,v)]
    df1_idx, df2_idx = zip(*idx)
    t = df1.iloc[list(df1_idx),0].reset_index(drop=True)
    t1 = df2.iloc[list(df2_idx),0].reset_index(drop=True)
    return pd.concat([t,t1],axis=1)

merge_regex(df1, df2)
  col1 col2
0    a   ab
1    a    a
2    b   ab
3    c   cd
4    d   cd
```

---

Timeit results

```
# My solution
In [292]: %timeit merge_regex(df1,df2)
1.21 ms ± 22.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#Chris's solution
In [293]: %%timeit
     ...: df1['matches'] = df1.apply(lambda r: [x for x in df2['col2'].values if re.findall(r['regex'], x)], axis=1)
     ...: 
     ...: df1.set_index('col1').explode('matches').reset_index().drop(columns=['regex'])
     ...:
     ...:
4.62 ms ± 25.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for doing this, incredibly helpful.

Comment: @patrick-bray Glad you found this helpful. I have another solution which faster than the suggested solution but it doesn't care about the column names. Should I post it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at each col1 value and find all of the values in col2 of df2 that the pattern matches and make a list and place it into a column called 'matches'. Once that's done you can set the col1 as index, explode the matches column to make them into one per row, then get rid of the regex pattern column.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d'], columns = ['col1'])
df1['regex'] = '.*' + df1['col1'] + '.*'
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['ab','a','cd'], columns = ['col2'])


df1['matches'] = df1.apply(lambda r: [x for x in df2['col2'].values if re.findall(r['regex'], x)], axis=1)

df1.set_index('col1').explode('matches').reset_index().drop(columns=['regex'])



        col1    matches
    0   a       ab
    1   a       a
    2   b       ab
    3   c       cd
    4   d       cd
```

Comment: `df.apply` over axis 1 is not recommended, look at this answer to know [more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/12416453). Not saying your answer is bad.

Comment: I totally agree w/you :)

Comment: Posted timeit results of your answer just to give an insight of performance. If you mind i'll remove it.

Comment: It's all good your answer is the correct one. Good work