# How to join DataFrames in Pandas with consideration of RegEx?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames, `df1` and `df2`.

As shown in the first DataFrame `df1`, the entries in the column "Box", which show the assignment of different boxes to a hand of people, can contain RegEx-values:

df1:

```
   Person        Box
0    Alex      Box 1
1   Linda      Box 3
2   David     Box .*
3  Rachel  Box [1-2]
```

df2:

```
     Box       Item  Qty.
0  Box 1      Apple     4
1  Box 1  Blueberry    12
2  Box 2      Lemon     1
3  Box 2     Papaya     2
4  Box 3      Apple     2
```

How do I join the DataFrames on the common column "Box" in a way that these regEx-values are evaluated correctly (as regex are not supported in pandas' join / merge-functions), so that I receive the following DataFrame as a result:

```
    Person    Box       Item  Qty.
0     Alex  Box 1      Apple     4
1     Alex  Box 1  Blueberry    12
2    Linda  Box 3      Apple     2
3    David  Box 1      Apple     4
4    David  Box 1  Blueberry    12
5    David  Box 2      Lemon     1
6    David  Box 2     Papaya     2
7    David  Box 3      Apple     2
8   Rachel  Box 1      Apple     4
9   Rachel  Box 1  Blueberry    12
10  Rachel  Box 2      Lemon     1
11  Rachel  Box 2     Papaya     2
```

---

I already tried to achieve this via list comprehensions, which leads to correct results, but drops columns of the left DataFrame.

```py
def joinWithRegEx(left: pd.DataFrame, right: pd.DataFrame, left_on: str, right_on: str):

    df = pd.DataFrame
    df = pd.concat([right[right[right_on].str.match(entry)] for entry in left[left_on]], ignore_index=True)
    '''
    Left-Join of two DataFrame with considered Rege
    '''
    return df
```

I would have actually thought that this would be a more common usecase, or is Pandas simply not the best choice for these kind if tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `df.iterrows` it is possible to store the remaining columns of the left dataframe and reassign them after applying the REGEX filter.
See verbose explanation in the commentaries of the updated function.

```py
def joinWithRegEx(left: pd.DataFrame, right: pd.DataFrame, left_on: str, right_on: str):

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    # iterate over the left dataframe
    for idx, row in left.iterrows():
        # store REGEX pattern
        regex = row[left_on]
        # store remaining columns
        preserved_values = row.drop(left_on)
        # filter the right dataframe
        match = right[right[right_on].str.match(regex)]
        # add the preserved remaining columns
        match = match.assign(**preserved_values)
        # append to the final dataframe
        df = pd.concat([df, match], ignore_index=True)

    '''
    Left-Join of two DataFrame with considered Regex
    '''
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several other answers for this use case.  Borrowing from: [Can I perform a left join/merge between two dataframes using regular expressions with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521616/can-i-perform-a-left-join-merge-between-two-dataframes-using-regular-expressions)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Alex','Box 1'],
    ['Linda','Box 3'],
    ['David','Box .*'],
    ['Rachel','Box [1-2]'], 
], columns=['Person','Box'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Box 1','Apple',4],
    ['Box 1','Blueberry',12],
    ['Box 2','Lemon',1],
    ['Box 2','Papaya',2],
    ['Box 3','Apple',2]
],columns=['Box','Item','Qty.'])

import re
def merge_regex(df1, df2,left_on,right_on):
    idx = [(i,j) for i,r in enumerate(left_on) for j,v in enumerate(right_on) if re.match(r,v)]
    df1_idx, df2_idx = zip(*idx)
    t = df1.iloc[list(df1_idx)].reset_index(drop=True)
    t1 = df2.iloc[list(df2_idx)].reset_index(drop=True)
    return pd.concat([t,t1],axis=1)

df = merge_regex(df1,df2,df1.Box,df2.Box)

#remove duplicate column
df = df.T.groupby(level=0).last().T

#reorder to match desired output
df = df[['Person','Box','Item','Qty.']]

df
    Person  Box Item    Qty.
0   Alex    Box 1   Apple   4
1   Alex    Box 1   Blueberry   12
2   Linda   Box 3   Apple   2
3   David   Box 1   Apple   4
4   David   Box 1   Blueberry   12
5   David   Box 2   Lemon   1
6   David   Box 2   Papaya  2
7   David   Box 3   Apple   2
8   Rachel  Box 1   Apple   4
9   Rachel  Box 1   Blueberry   12
10  Rachel  Box 2   Lemon   1
11  Rachel  Box 2   Papaya  2
```